# new Model() that has fields set as select:false are not available

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my Schema:

```
var userScheme = mongoose.Schema({
aField:String,
info: {
     type:{
          local: {
                 email:String
                 }
          },
     select:false
      }

});
```

When I try to create a new user this works fine:

```
var newUser = new User()
newUser.aField="Something"
newUser.save()
```

But when I try to access the field that has select:false, I can't access the data. so this doesn't work:

```
var newUser = new User()
newUser.aField="something"
newUser.info.local.email="email@domain.com"
newUser.save()
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined
```

My guess is that the new Model is returned without the info field becuase it is set to select:false.

How can I make the new Model() return all the fields including those set to 'select:false'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the select:false had nothing to do with it.

The culprit was the fact that info has no values by default and there for was not included in the model at all.

The solution was to create a new schema just for info, and to include it in the user schema like this:

```
var userScheme = mongoose.Schema({
    aField:String,
    info: {
        type:infoSchema,
        default:infoSchema, //Without this, the new document will still not include an 'info' document,
        select:false
    }

});
```

Hope this helps anyone. This was just 3 hours of my life.